# Python Rock/Paper/Scissors with name input

Tags: python

I'm creating a rock paper scissors game in python. The way I've done it is below. However instead of printing player 1 and player 2 I want to have them be actual names. So, it could say John Wins or Joe Wins. How can I implement a raw_input for the player name to print each time.

```
player1 = raw_input('Enter rock/paper/scissors: ')
player2 = raw_input('Enter rock/paper/scissors: ')

if (player1 == player2):
    print "The game is a Tie"
elif (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors'):
    print "player 1 wins"
elif (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'paper'):
    print "player 2 wins"
elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock'):
    print "player 1 wins"
elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors'):
    print "player 2 wins"
elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper'):
    print "player 1 wins"
elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock'):
    print "player 2 wins"
else:
    print "Invalid input"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add two more variables containing the players names:

```
player1_name = raw_input('Player1 please enter your name: ')
player2_name = raw_input('Player2 please enter your name: ')
```

And then when you want to declare a winner use either:

```
print (player1_name + 'wins')
print (player2_name + 'wins')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first_player_name = input("Please enter your name :")
second_player_name = input("Please enter your name :")

# your code is here

print (first_player_name + " Wins!") # instead every player 1 wins
print (second_player_name + " Wins!") # instead every player 2 wins
```